# Store arbitrary data into object instance

Tags: multithreading, delphi, rtti, method-invocation

Consider the following example:

```
type

  TTestClass = class
    public
      procedure method1; virtual;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
    vmi: TVirtualMethodInterceptor;
    ttc: TTestClass;
  end;

{ Initially SomeFlag is PostponeExecution }
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  vmi := TVirtualMethodInterceptor.Create(TTestClass);
  ttc := TTestClass.Create;

  vmi.OnBefore :=
    procedure(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
      const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean;
        out Result: TValue)
    begin
      if { SomeFlag = DirectExecution } then
        DoInvoke := true
      else
      begin
        { SomeFlag := DirectExecution }
        TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
          procedure
          begin                
            // Invoke() will trigger vmi.OnBefore 
            // because Instance is the proxified object
            // I want to keep "Self" to be the proxified object
            Method.Invoke(Instance, Args);
          end
        ).Start;
      end
    end;

  vmi.Proxify(ttc);

  ttc.method1;

end;

{ TTestClass }

procedure TTestClass.method1;
begin
  //  Do something async
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  vmi.Unproxify(ttc);
  vmi.Free;
  ttc.Free;
end;
```

I want hooked virtual method to execute itself in a thread i.e. delay/defer its execution.

For this purpose I use TVirtualMethodInterceptor to intercept virtual methods of a given class. When a virtual method is invoked vmi.OnBefore is fired. This is simplified representation of my idea:

Call_VirtualMethod(method1) -> OnBefore_fires_1 -> CreateThread_and_InvokeAgain -> OnBefore_fires_2 -> DoInvoke := true (i.e. directly execute the method)

Explanation:

1. Initially SomeFlag has a value of PostponeExecution.
2. The first call to ttc.method1 will trigger OnBefore event
   (OnBefore_fires_1). The method will not execute, because SomeFlag is
   PostponeExecution. Therefore a thread will be created which will set
   SomeFlag to DirectExecute and will invoke the same method again, but
   within the thread's context.
3. Then OnBefore fires again (because Instance is the proxified object
       i.e. the method is the hooked method). This time SomeFlag is
       DirectExecute and the method will be invoked.

I use proxified object (Instance var) when invoking the method, because I want "Self" to point to it. This way if method1 calls other virtual method of the same class the later will also be automatically executed in a thread.

For this to happen I need to store the flag somewhere i.e. indicate OnBefore's second call what to do. 
My question is how/where to store "SomeFlag" so it's accessible during the two calls of OnBefore?
The solution should be cross-platform. Suggestions/other solutions are also welcome.

I imagine it can be done with VMT patching ([link1](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2007/05/hack17-virtual-class-variables-part-i.html), [link2](http://www.deltics.co.nz/blog/posts/307), [link3](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=336)), but VirtualProtect is a Windows only function so cross-platform requirement would be violated.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

**What's this all about:**

Imagine you can have this kind of class in Delphi:

```
TBusinessLogic = class
  public
    // Invokes asynchronously
    [InvokeType(Async)]
    procedure QueryDataBase;

    // Invokes asynchronously and automatically return asocciated ITask (via OnBefore event)
    [InvokeType(Await)]
    function DownloadFile(AUrl: string): ITask;

    // This method touches GUI i.e. synchonized
    [InvokeType(VclSend)]
    procedure UpdateProgressBar(AValue: integer);

    // Update GUI via TThread.Queue
    [InvokeType(VclPost)]
    procedure AddTreeviewItem(AText: string);

end;

...

procedure TBusinessLogic.QueryDataBase;
begin
  // QueryDataBase is executed ASYNC (QueryDataBase is tagged as Async)
  // Do heavy DB Query here

  // Updating GUI is easy, because AddTreeviewItem is tagged as VclPost
  for SQLRec in SQLRecords do
    AddTreeviewItem(SQLRec.FieldByName["CustomerName"].asString);
end;
```

This approach really simplifies threading and synchronization. No more ducktyping TThread.Synchronize(), TThread.Queue() etc. 
You just focus on the business logic and call appropriate methods - OnBefore event does the "dirty" job for you. Very close to Await methods in C#.

This is the main idea!

**UPDATE:**
*I re-edited the entire question to make it more clear.*

Comment: Why not adding the `PostponeExecution` argument to your `InvokeMethod` and make it `True` by default and then inside the anonymous method call it with `False`?

Comment: @StefanGlienke I cannot modify InvokeMethod's signature. I mean I prepared a minified showcase for my question. InvokeMethod belongs to a system class and has other name.

Comment: You cannot change the signature but you can change its implementation? Well then move the implementation to another method with the additional argument and call it from the original one. I don't see why the requirement would dictate the implementation. Anyway storing the state of the invokation to the method or object instance is just wrong and should not be done.

Comment: @StefanGlienke in fact InvokeMethod is an anonymous method that is called on specific event. So the event itself is called two times. And I now I see the example is not precise...I'll make correction a little bit later.

Comment: You can have an overloaded `InvokeMethod()` passing the required state, with a default value if you like.

Comment: @LURD, I'll edit the entire question, because the main idea is unclear.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I edited the question. It now represents the full picture.

Comment: Can't you just test `GetCurrentThreadID <> MainThreadID` ?

Comment: @LURD ttc.method1() may be called from another thread so MainThreadID  doesn't play here. Currently this implementation is not threadsafe, but it will become once I get an answer.

Comment: My question is WHY do you need to do this? Absent some requirement to work this way, this sounds like the beginning of some large pile of technical debt.

Comment: @WarrenP look under "What's this all about" in the question.

Comment: I see. I think you should provide a different technique.  Invoke QueryDatabaseComplete yourself, on completion, when the user calls QueryDatabase, where QueryDatabase is somehow auto-generated, and the whole thing is based on interfaces (IBusinessLogic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. What you try to do is basically call the virtual method but without going through the interceptor again. Since the interceptor itself has registered stubs inside the VMT calling the method through invoke will hit the interceptor stub again causing a recursion.

I have done this in the past in the Spring4D interception by doing the invoking on a lower level using the `Rtti.Invoke` routine.

This is how you do it:

```
procedure DirectlyInvokeMethod(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
  const Args: TArray<TValue>);
var
  params: TArray<TRttiParameter>;
  values: TArray<TValue>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  params := Method.GetParameters;
  SetLength(values, Length(Args) + 1);
  values[0] := Instance;

  // convert arguments for Invoke call (like done in the DispatchInvoke methods
  for i := Low(Args) to High(Args) do
    PassArg(params[i], args[i], values[i + 1], Method.CallingConvention); // look at Rtti.pas for PassArg

  Rtti.Invoke(Method.CodeAddress, values, Method.CallingConvention, nil);
end;
```

Since you are calling this asynchronously I left handling of functions out - otherwise you have to check the ReturnType of Method to pass the correct handle, here we are just passing nil.

For the PassArg routine look into the System.Rtt.pas.

Then you just call it like this:

```
vmi.OnBefore :=
  procedure(Instance: TObject; Method: TRttiMethod;
    const Args: TArray<TValue>; out DoInvoke: Boolean;
      out Result: TValue)
  begin
    DoInvoke := Method.Parent.Handle = TObject.ClassInfo; // this makes sure you are not intercepting any TObject virtual methods
    if not DoInvoke then // otherwise call asynchronously
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
        procedure
        begin
          DirectlyInvokeMethod(Instance, Method, Args);
        end).Start;
  end;
```

Keep in mind that any var or out parameters are a no go for this approach for obvious reasons.

Comment: Obviously I didn't know Rtti.Invoke will bypass interceptor stub :) I'll try it later. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be Instance var passed to DirectlyInvokeMethod as first argument? Also Rtti.Invoke should receive values array instead of args?